# Is there a general pocedure to finding the principal matrix solution of first-order linear ode systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

(Title reformulated:) What is $\prod (t,t_0)$ for $$x(t)'=A(t) x(t),$$ where $A \in M^{2\times 2}$ with coefficients of the form $at+b$?

I have been trying to find examples [online](http://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/suppnotes/suppnotes03/ls6.pdf), but can only find examples with constant coefficients, which are easier to solve.

Unfortunately I cannot add anything more to this question, I have no idea where to start. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I don't believe there is an elementary solution.  For example, with 
$$A(t) = \pmatrix{1+t & 3+2 t\cr 3-2t& -2-t}$$
the solution requires Heun functions.